# NetSuite/Suitescript/Workflow: How do I open a URL from a field after clicking button?

Tags: url, hyperlink, netsuite, suitescript

I have a workflow that adds a button "Open Link" and a field on the record called "URL" that contains a hyperlink to an attachment in NetSuite. I want to add a workflow action script that opens this url in a different page. I have added the script and the workflow action to the workflow. My script:

```
function openURL() {  

var url = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_url');

window.open(url);    

}
```

I get this script error after clicking the button: "TypeError: Cannot find function open in object [object Object].

How can I change my script so it opens the URL in the field?

(This function works when I try it in the console)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want it to work when the record is being viewed or edited?  They have slightly different scripts.  I'm going to assume you want the button to work when the record is being viewed, but I'll write it so it works even when the document is being edited as well.

The hard part about the way Netsuite has set it up is that it requires two scripts, a user event script, and a client script.  The way @michoel suggests may work too... I've never inserted the script by text before personally though. 
 I'll try that sometime today perhaps.

Here's a user event you could use (haven't tested it myself though, so you should run it through a test before deploying it to everyone).

```
function userEvent_beforeLoad(type, form, request)
{
    /*
    Add the specified client script to the document that is being shown
    It looks it up by id, so you'll want to make sure the id is correct
    */
    form.setScript("customscript_my_client_script");

    /*
    Add a button to the page which calls the openURL() method from a client script
    */
    form.addButton("custpage_open_url", "Open URL", "openURL()");    
}
```

Use this as the Suitescript file for a User Event script.  Set the Before Load function in the Script Page to **userEvent_beforeLoad**.  Make sure to deploy it to the record you want it to run on.

Here's the client script to go with it.

```
function openURL()
{
    /*
    nlapiGetFieldValue() gets the url client side in a changeable field, which nlapiLookupField (which looks it up server side) can't do
    if your url is hidden/unchanging or you only care about view mode, you can just get rid of the below and use nlapiLookupField() instead
    */
    var url = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_url');

    /*
    nlapiGetFieldValue() doesn't work in view mode (it returns null), so we need to use nlapiLookupField() instead
    if you only care about edit mode, you don't need to use nlapiLookupField so you can ignore this
    */
    if(url == null)
    {
        var myType = nlapiGetRecordType();
        var myId = nlapiGetRecordId();
        url = nlapiLookupField(myType, myId,'custbody_url');
    }

    //opening up the url
    window.open(url);    
}
```

Add it as a Client Script, but don't make any deployments (the User Event Script will attach it to the form for you).  Make sure this script has the id **customscript_my_client_script** (or whatever script id you used in the user event script in form.setScript()) or else this won't work.

Another thing to keep in mind is that each record can only have one script appended to it using form.setScript() (I think?) so you may want to title the user event script and client script something related to the form you are deploying it on.  Using form.setScript is equivalent to setting the script value when you are in the Customize Form menu.

If you can get @michoel's answer working, that may end up being better because you're keeping the logic all in one script which (from my point of view) makes it easier to manage your Suitescripts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are running into is that Workflow Action Scripts execute on the server side, so you are not able to perform client side actions like opening up a new tab. I would suggest using a User Event Script which can "inject" client code into the button onclick function.

```
function beforeLoad(type, form) {
  var script = "window.open(nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_url'))";
  form.addButton('custpage_custom_button', 'Open URL', script);
}
```

Comment: This opens up a blank page for me. Even when I try to add:

`var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('vendorbill', nlapiGetRecordId());
     var url = rec.getFieldValue('custbody_url');`

and try to open this page, it does not do anything and stays on the page